# Is there a way to specify an html class name to be just even ( not odd ) to get just even css attributes?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a library that specify give some `CSS` attributes to a the child of a class depending if it's *even* or *odd*, example :

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child" > <div class="puppy">content Odd</div></div> 
<div class="child" > <div class="puppy">content Even</div></div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .parent:nth-child(even) .child {
                   css attributes: whatever;
                   ...
                   }
.parent:nth-child(even) .child .puppy{
                   css attributes: whatever;
                   ...
                   }
.parent:nth-child(odd) .child {
                   css attributes: whatever;
                   ...
                   }
.parent:nth-child(odd) .child .puppy{
                   css attributes: whatever;
                   ...
                   }
```

How to specify the child class to be just even and not odd, **without** overriding all the CSS properties with `!important`.

## Clarification:

> [So] you have a library that is applying alternative styles to even and odd children, but you want to style everything as if they were all even children?

```css
  .puppy:nth-child(odd) {
  background: SpringGreen ;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 30;
}

    
 .puppy:nth-child(even){
  background: Teal ;
  margin-left: 30;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: azure;  
}
.yop{
 width: 400px;
 height: 700px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 4px solid LightGrey ;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px LightGrey ;
}
.puppy{
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display:table;
  font-size: 18
}
```

```html
<div class="yop">
 <div class="puppy">
 content<strong> Odd</strong>
 </div>
<div class="puppy">content<strong> Even</strong></div>
<div class="puppy">content <strong>Odd</strong></div> 
<div class="puppy">content<strong> Even</strong></div>
<div class="puppy">content <strong>Odd</strong></div> 
<div class="puppy">content<strong> Even</strong></div>
 <div class="puppy">content <strong>Odd</strong></div> 
<div class="puppy">content<strong> Even</strong></div>
</div>
```

Above is a code example: how to tag puppy div as even so they take the same position ( as "content even" divs ) without overriding existing CSS and putting !important every where.

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking. Perhaps a bad translation?

Comment: If you include your css after library, you could just use `.htmlClass:nth-child(even)` and redeclare some attributes, I think? If not, try to use `!important` after the attribute.

Comment: Thank you Teuniz for the answer, i can't override all the css with !important because there are many classes attributes, it will become a bit messy, that's why i'm looking for a more clean way to rely the class name to the even declarations in css. Chris it was not translation, i tought i was clear and simple.

Comment: I'm with Chris on this, it's not clear what you're asking. Are you saying that you have a library that is applying alternative styles to even and odd children, but you want to style everything as if they were all even children?

Comment: Roddy, i just improved the question, yes that's exactly what i'm looking for, the css is  already compiled in react modules that's why i'am saying library.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple way to set odd and even children by css. Hope this help!

```css
.parent .child > div {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.parent .child:nth-child(2n) > div {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child" > <div class="puppy">content Odd</div></div> 
<div class="child" > <div class="puppy">content Even</div></div>
<div class="child" > <div class="puppy">content Odd</div></div> 
<div class="child" > <div class="puppy">content Even</div></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `nth` selector on the wrong element. You need to move it to the `.child`

```
 .parent .child:nth-child(even) {
                                css attributes: 
                                ...
                                 }
.parent .child:nth-child(even) .puppy{
                               css attributes: 
                                ...
                                 }
.parent .child:nth-child(odd) {
                              css attributes: 
                                ...
                                 }
.parent .child:nth-child(odd) .puppy{
                              css attributes: 
                                ...
                                 }
```

You're trying to affect the `child` element. What you have in your example is the selecting the `parent` element.